# Unable to select and click link anchor tag by xpath, it is returning an array with 1 element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<a href="MappingAndEnrichmentSetUp.aspx" title="Mapping &amp; Enrichment" class="rpLink rpExpandable  rpSelected" target="ctl00_DefaultContent_radPaneProjectMaintContent">
    <span class="rpOut rpNavigation">
        <span class=""></span>
        <span class="rpText" style="">Mapping &amp; Enrichment</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Here is what I get from console

```
a=$x("//a[@title='Mapping & Enrichment']")
```

Output:

```
[a.rpLink.rpExpandable]
```

at index 0 it has the link and hidden **photo** element

```
a[0].click()  --works fine
```

a -- returning an array

Is it possible to get the anchor tag directly using xpath for above html snippet?

I am using the following code in java testNG class to click the link. It is not working.

Console debug:

```
a=$x("(//a[@href='ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx'])")
[a.rpLink]
  0: a.rpLinklength: 
  1__proto__: Array(0)

a=$x("(//a[@href='ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx'])")[0]
<a href=​"ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx" title=​"Project Dimensions" class=​"rpLink" target=​"ctl00_DefaultContent_radPaneProjectMaintContent">​…​</a>​
```

Is there any way to select the  element via xpath directly?
so that, I can use a.click() from testNG Java WebElement

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("XPATH_TO_SELECT_ANCHOR_TAG_NOT_ARRAY_WITH_ANCHOR_TAG"))).click();
```

Java Console log:
[Java Log TestNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnxtA.png)

```
JavaScript warning: http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/XXXXX/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=DefaultMasterScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4ae4914f-8c8e-4123-9d05-414d87b48357%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2014.1.225.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3afe3df733-ee56-4563-8789-bc399360084a%3a16e4e7cd%3aed16cbdc%3af7645509%3a88144a7a%3a24ee1bba%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a7165f74%3a1e771326%3aa7e79140%3a2003d0b8%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3a58366029%3ab7778d6c%3ae085fe68%3ae330518b%3ac128760b%3ac8618e41%3ae4f8f289%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94, line 2030: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript warning: http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/XXXXX/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=DefaultMasterScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4ae4914f-8c8e-4123-9d05-414d87b48357%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2014.1.225.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3afe3df733-ee56-4563-8789-bc399360084a%3a16e4e7cd%3aed16cbdc%3af7645509%3a88144a7a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a333f8d94%3a11a04f7e%3af46195d3%3a4cacbc31%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3a7165f74%3a874f8ea2, line 2030: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript warning: http://IP_XXXXXXXX/XXXXXX/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=DefaultMasterScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a4ae4914f-8c8e-4123-9d05-414d87b48357%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2014.1.225.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3afe3df733-ee56-4563-8789-bc399360084a%3a16e4e7cd%3aed16cbdc%3af7645509%3a88144a7a%3a24ee1bba%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a19620875%3a874f8ea2%3af46195d3%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a7165f74%3ab7778d6c%3a2003d0b8%3a1e771326%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3a8674cba1%3a7c926187%3a2e42e72a%3aa51ee93e%3aef347303%3ac08e9f8a%3a2bef5fcc%3ae06b58fd%3ae085fe68%3aa9b7ace7, line 2030: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
[Parent 19988, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Parent 19988, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 6324, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 6324, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_chann[Cehildl_win. 19cc, lin648, Chrome_Ce 346
hildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Parent 19988, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 19204, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 19204, Chrome_ChildThread] *** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
[GPU 19676, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNIN
###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: So you can locate link, but cannot click it or what? Is it hidden?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Please post the complete error message or explain what the expected behavior is and what you are seeing.

Comment: Hi @Jeffc , I have added extra info as per suggestion. Please look into this.

Comment: Hello  @Andersson , I am not able to locate the link, I have updated the question with extra info. Please look at that once.

Comment: Hello @muraliselenium , I have updated the question. Please check once and help here.

Comment: Remove `a=` from your console commands... it's not necessary and will get you your answer faster unless you are specifically trying to store the result in a variable. You still have `It is not working.` when referencing your Java code but have not posted the related error message. You should be able to use the same XPath that you have in the console. The element is likely not visible or you need a wait but we can't do anything but guess until you've provided the necessary info.

Comment: Hi @JeffC ... Please tell me where can I find Java code log. Is it console of java , where I run the testng.xml. i.e. in Eclipse ? Please tell me. I am new to testNG framework and selenium.

Comment: When you run the test in Eclipse, if it fails or throws an exception, you should be able to find the error message in the Console. See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-console_view.htm)

Comment: Hello @JeffC, I have added the logs now. Please help.

Comment: I see you added the logs but none of those look related to Selenium and it looks like it's cut off at the end. Please post a link to the page

Comment: Sorry @JeffC. That page is internally hosted to the organisation. I am not able to post the page link. However, I will try to reproduce it and then post. I am not sure though, I will be able to reproduce with a dummy page. Any suggestion on what is possible go wrong, there is no frame in this page.

Comment: @JeffC the javascript log , as you can see in above is selecting an array with link at 0th index. However, I want to select the link by xpath. That will let me get clickable web element in java driver.

Comment: Since you've tested the locator in the dev console and it's finding an element, it's hard to say without you trying the same locator using Java/Selenium code and reporting back the error message. It could be 1. in an IFRAME (which you've said it isn't), 2. it could be a timing issue (but you've used a 20s wait) so without more data or access to the page, I have no idea. The Java error message is key.

Comment: You are using an XPath... just paste it into the Java code, e.g. `new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@href='ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx']"))).click();`

Comment: Yes @JeffC . You see in browser console also ` $x("(//a[@href='ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx'])").click() ` is not working. However, ` $x("(//a[@href='ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx'])")[0].click() ` is working. So How can I implement ` $x("(//a[@href='ProjectDimensionSetUp.aspx'])")[0].click() ` in java.

Comment: Let's back up for a sec... `$x()` returns a collection. You cannot `.click()` a collection so that's why it doesn't work and why `$x()[0].click()` does because it's using an array index to get the first element from the collection. In Selenium, if you run `driver.findElement().click()` it will work just fine even if more than one element is found because it just executes the `.click()` on the first element returned by design.

Comment: To do the equivalent to `$x()` in Selenium, you would use `driver.findElements()`... and to choose a particular member of the collection you would use `.get(x)` where `x` is the index of the element you want, e.g. `driver.findElements().get(1)` would return the *second* item in the collection (first element is 0th index, second is 1, and so on).

Comment: Oh thanks @JeffC a lot. This will definitely help me proceed. I was unaware of what you explained now. :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I've compiled several of my comments into an answer. See if that summarizes what you were looking for. Let me know if something is missing, etc.

Comment: @JeffC Sure . I will try and let you know. :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From our conversation in the comments, it sounds like you are confusing a couple things.

In the browser console, executing `$x()` returns a collection of elements so `$x().click()` doesn't work because you can't click an entire collection. If you use array notation, you can specify a member of the collection you want to click, e.g. `$x()[0].click()` will click the first element in the collection.

To translate this into Java/Selenium, `driver.findElements()` (plural) is sort of an equivalent to `$x()` in that they both return a collection of elements. If you use `driver.findElement()` (singular), it is designed to only return the first element even if multiple elements are located. So, you can use `driver.findElement().click()` safely, even if the locator used finds multiple elements.

If you want to use a locator that returns multiple elements but don't want to get just the first element, you would use `.get(x)` where `x` is the index of the element you want in the collection. For example, `driver.findElements().get(1)` would return the *second* element (0 is the index of the first element, 1 is the index of the second, and so on).

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML you have provided to invoke `click()` on the *link* with text as **Mapping & Enrichment** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='rpLink rpExpandable  rpSelected' and @href='MappingAndEnrichmentSetUp.aspx']/span[@class='rpOut rpNavigation']//span[@class='rpText']"))).click();
```

Comment: Your locator is way too overly specific and fragile with all the string matching on classes, etc. We don't even know what the error message is, how do you know that a wait will solve the problem?